# Docusign return url change parameter

Tags: docusignapi

The parameter 'event=signing_complete'  is automatically add in docusign embedded signing. I want to change this something like 'success=signing_complete' or 'complete=signing_complete' or 'thanks=signing_complete' like that. Is there is any way to change that parameter 'event' ??.

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry, the return `event` parameter and its values are all constants.

Also, if there are additional signers for the envelope after the embedded signer, then the envelope's status will not be complete until all of the recipients/signers have been processed.

Comment: I am facing a strange issue, docuSign is truncating one of the query parameter which I set in my returnUrl. Any idea.

Comment: How long are your query parameters? There may be a total length limit on either the url as a whole or your qps. Please open a new stackoverflow question to discuss.